# How to know when silent nested installer has completed when using InnoSetup?

Tags: windows-installer, inno-setup, silent-installer

I have created a software suite installer using InnoSetup that when executed,

1. Shows a list of software for user to download/install.
2. Downloads selected software and install them silently for user.

I am using **inno-download-plugin** for downloading software.

I am using the following code in `ssInstall` to silently install each software:

```pascal
ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\MirrorLink.exe'), '/VERYSILENT', '',
    SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
```

This solution works fine except that some software need computer to restart to work properly. Therefore I implemented `function NeedRestart(): Boolean;` to show restart page if those software that require reboot is selected by the user.

My question is, since I don't know when silent install finishes, I risk a chance that the computer will be restarted when software is in the middle of installation. I know I can use `sleep()` function in `ssInstall`, but i don't think it will work reliably because some computer might take longer to install than others.

So my question is, is there a better approach to detect whether a silent install has finished so I can show NeedRestart page to the user?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ewWaitUntilTerminated` instead of `ewNoWait` to wait for the child installer to finish.

See [Pascal Scripting: ShellExec](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_shellexec).